# Дэплой spring boot проекта на tomcat server

Tags: spring, tomcat, boot

Я локально поднял сервер томката , потом загружаю свою варку через tomcat manager html однако не могу стартануть свою war ку после развертывание.Получаю ошибку в логах 
Could not resolve placeholder 'spring.profiles.active' in value "${spring.profiles.active}". Как я понимаю мое приложение не может понять какой profile запустить . Я добавил в папке bin томката stenv.bat содержанием set SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=dev , однако не помогает

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего у вас в **application.properties** приложения либо нет переменной **spring.profiles.active**, либо она объявлена неправильно.

Еще может быть, если у вас путь к конфигурации переопределяется после деплоя, то после переопределения в **application.properties** нет настройки.

Если приложите **application.properties** и полный лог приложения при старте, то смогу сказать более конкретно.